# Wordpress - Limiting Number of Posts

Tags: php, wordpress

How can I adapt this code to limit the number of posts to say 3 on the page? It's taken from a Wordpress template. Thanks in advance for any help!

```
<?php 
            if ( get_query_var('paged') ) {
                    $paged = get_query_var('paged');
            } elseif ( get_query_var('page') ) {
                    $paged = get_query_var('page');
            } else {
                    $paged = 1;
            }
            $alt_args  = array(
                'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
                'paged' => $paged
            );
            $alt_posts = new WP_Query($alt_args);
        ?>

        <?php if ( $alt_posts->have_posts() ) : ?>

<?php while ( $alt_posts->have_posts() ) : $alt_posts->the_post(); ?>

<?php get_template_part( 'content', 'alt-homepage' ); ?>

<?php endwhile; ?>


<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

                <?php else : ?>
<article id="post-0" class="post no-results not-found">
                    <header class="entry-header">
                        <h1 class="entry-title"><?php _e( 'Nothing Found', 'wp-jurist' ); ?></h1>
```

Comment: Go into wordpress admin and change the [posts per page] option.

Comment: I need the posts per page to be different on different pages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set the posts_per_page parameter:

```
$alt_args  = array(
            'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
            'paged' => $paged,
            'posts_per_page' => 3
        );
```

see http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters for details

Comment: That's what I thought would work but when I add that in, I get 

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING, expecting ')' in /home/a3407884/public_html/wp-content/themes/dia/alt_homepage_with_gallery.php on line 46

Comment: @user3658420 thats a syntax error, did you forget the comma after the $paged variable? `'paged' => $paged,` <--here

Comment: Great, now working. I will look more carefully next time! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

While is not the right thing to do, this will work:

```
<?php 
$i = 0;
while ( $alt_posts->have_posts() && $i < 3 ) {
    $i++;
    $alt_posts->the_post(); 
    get_template_part( 'content', 'alt-homepage' );
} ?>
```

The code above will limit the maximum of proccessed elements to 3. Just change the while part, and it'll run. Anyway, the correctness would be that the have_post() method would have an option to limit the number of elements retrieved, and then only show that elements.